# Disable AD User with PowerShell at a specific time

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to disable an AD user at a specific time like 11.30 am automatically. I can disable user manually with the below command

```
Disable-ADAccount -Identity username
```

and also set the the expiry data by using this command

```
Set-ADUser -Identity username -AccountExpirationDate
```

need to disable automatically at the given time. is it possible to achieve that without a task scheduler?

```
Disable-ADAccount -Identity username
Set-ADUser -Identity username -AccountExpirationDate
```

Comment: To my understanding this should be done thru a scheduled task. You can monitor any expired non disabled account and disable them

Comment: Yes, through the task schedule I can achieve this, but I don't want to register task every time for this small thing

Comment: So you want to build your own task scheduler? This small thing can be a task template that you simply pass the date and username into during creation. Why would you reinvent the wheel? There is also new-ScheduledJob

Comment: And don’t forget account expiration. However I don’t think that disabled the user, just prevents login.

Comment: I don't think there is something better than a scheduled task in this case. Finding expired accounts and disabling them is literally 1 line of code.

Comment: Account expiration is preventing the user from login. It is not disabling the user. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Why do you want to disable the account at a specific time? The settings doesn't take effect until the user tries to logon the next time anyhow.

Comment: @Dennis because I need to disable the AD account of the user who is leaving the organization. And if some are not available at that time so it is a little difficult to manage. like if my HR asks me to disable an account at 10 pm today. so I have to disable it manually.

Comment: Yes, but disabling an AD account at a certain time doesn't mean that **current** session will stop. Only new sessions. So to really make sure a user can't continue to work, you have to disable all current sessions as well. Disabling the account won't do that. So the exact time it is disabled isn't that important.

Comment: @Dennis I just want to reduce human intervention to disable the account by automating the process that is only my concern.

Comment: Ok, so why don't you use ExpirationDate as a scheduled "disable". It will have the same result. And then use a script at your discretion that disables all accounts that has expired?  If you don't want to automate it using Scheduled Tasks, then perhaps do that while you are doing the monthly patching? You cold write event driven scripts, but Scheduled Tasks is the easiest way in that regard.

Comment: Ok, so why don't you use ExpirationDate as a scheduled "disable". It will have the same result. And then use a script at your discretion that disables all accounts that has expired?  If you don't want to automate it using Scheduled Tasks, then perhaps do that while you are doing the monthly patching? You cold write event driven scripts, but Scheduled Tasks is the easiest way in that regard.

Comment: Oh, and you only need to register the Scheduled Task once. Just set it to start at recurring intervals.